# How to get load balanced access to different microservices ( Using ribbon, Springboot)

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

Consider a scenario: `MasterApp( microservice 1)` needs to call `AssistApp( Microservice 2)` to get data set `A` and `tertiaryApp ( microservice 3)` to get data set `B`.
Each `Microservice ( 2 and 3) has 3 instance which needs to be load balanced( Ribbon is getting used for client side load balancing).
Can you please let me know How should I prepare application.properties. I cannot put all 6 instance under property list of servers .

I have searched google( Dzone, nginx, spring examples in github and other forums), for a while but I was not able to find a conclusion for this Scenario.

Comment: You should choose a service registry such as eureka or consul.

Comment: I was using eurkea, but while doing the poc all the examples I was looking on net were enlisting the list of server in property file, so I was confused. Later on As @Chao Jiang suggested, I didn't need to know the uri and port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't config anything in `application.properties`.
I think you already have a param `spring.application.name` in your `application.properties`. And also, you have register your application into Eureka.

Then your call should be :

`restTemplate.getForObject("http://SERVICE_NAME/xx/yy")`

You don't need care about your 3 instance ip/port, just keep them the same application name.

Also, you should consider `Feign`,  it will more convinced for your requirement.